# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have installed Python 2.5.4, Numpy 1.5.0 win32, Matplotlib 1.0.0 win32, pywin32 218. Still not able to plot graphs in Python. Here is the error I am getting :

```
      import pylab
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
      from matplotlib.pylab import *
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 216, in <module>
      from matplotlib import mpl  # pulls in most modules
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl.py", line 1, in <module>
      from matplotlib import artist
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 6, in <module>
      from transforms import Bbox, IdentityTransform, TransformedBbox, TransformedPath
   File "C:\Python25\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 34, in <module>
      from matplotlib._path import affine_transform
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Please kindly help..

Comment: How did you install it?  This looks like some of the c-extensions are not properly compiled/installed.

Comment: For scientific python on windows, your best bet is to install WinPython, Python(x,y), Enthought Python or Anaconda rather than trying to install everything manually. Any of these will install most packages you are likely to need, and should configure them correctly.

Comment: Loading `...\site-packages\matplotlib\_path.pyd` with Dependency Walker might give you some clues on which DLL its about. If its all compiled properly it might also be a PATH issue, perhaps another version of the DLL is picked up because it comes 'first' in the PATH variable. This site has good precompiled binaries for Windows: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Thank you all for answering my query, but the actual problem was different and I found its solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be

Answer (score 26, accepted):

(I found this answer from a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmvRF7koJ5E)

1. Download `msvcp71.dll` and `msvcr71.dll` from the web.
2. Save them to your `C:\Windows\System32` folder.
3. Save them to your `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder as well (if you have a 64-bit operating system).

Now try running your code file in Python and it will load the graph in couple of seconds.

Comment: Saved my day! But why is it picking up from proper paths?

Comment: If that's is not the way, request @JFFIGK to please suggest the solution.

Comment: Pefhaps it is simpler than this? When I had the same error in another context, I followed 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44537131/numpy-library-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be

and there the answer of @User1024, adding a Path variable.

Comment: Please don't trust dlls found on some YouTube video - this is a really dangerous solution. Install the needed dlls from official Microsoft sources if possible.

Comment: Hi. I tried this, however, it doesn't solve my problem. Not sure why.

Comment: I'm getting the same error for the news3k package myself now, just out of the blue after having used it for months and not made any apparent change (but I get a different backtrace). How did you know that it was `msvcp71.dll`and `msvcr71.dll` that was missing?

Answer (score 31):

I had the same issue with importing matplotlib.pylab with Python 3.5.1 on Win 64. Installing the Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2015 from this links: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 fixed the missing DLLs.

I find it better and easier than downloading and pasting DLLs.

Comment: Had a similar problem with spacy on Windows 7, Python 3.7.6 from python.org. 
The stacktrace was

File "C:\Users\user_profile\Desktop\new_pro\venv\lib\site-packages\spacy\pipeline\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .pipes import Tagger, DependencyParser, EntityRecognizer, EntityLinker
  File "pipes.pyx", line 1, in init spacy.pipeline.pipes
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

With the link above it finally worked. You saved my day!

Answer (score 24):

For `Windows 10 x64`  and `Python`:

Open a Visual Studio x64 command prompt, and use [dumpbin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-command-line?view=msvc-160):

```
dumpbin /dependents [Python Module DLL or PYD file]
```

If you do not have Visual Studio installed, it is possible to download dumpbin elsewhere, or use another utility such as [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/).

Note that all other answers (to date) are simply random stabs in the dark, whereas this method is closer to a sniper rifle with night vision.

#### Case study 1

1. I switched on [Address Sanitizer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/) for a Python module that I wrote using C++ using MSVC and CMake.
2. It was giving this error: `ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`
3. Opened a Visual Studio x64 command prompt.
4. Under Windows, a `.pyd` file is a `.dll` file in disguise, so we want to run dumpbin on this file.
5. `cd MyLibrary\build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\Debug`
6. `dumpbin /dependents MyLibrary.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` which prints this:

   ```
   Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 14.27.29112.0
   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


   Dump of file MyLibrary.cp37-win_amd64.pyd

   File Type: DLL

     Image has the following dependencies:

       clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll
       gtestd.dll
       tbb_debug.dll
       python37.dll
       KERNEL32.dll
       MSVCP140D.dll
       VCOMP140D.DLL
       VCRUNTIME140D.dll
       VCRUNTIME140_1D.dll
       ucrtbased.dll

     Summary

        1000 .00cfg
       D6000 .data
        7000 .idata
       46000 .pdata
      341000 .rdata
       23000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
      856000 .text
   ```
7. Searched for `clang_rt.asan_dbg_dynamic-x86_64.dll`, copied it into the same directory, problem solved.
8. Alternatively, could [update the environment variable PATH](https://www.techjunkie.com/environment-variables-windows-10/) to point to the directory with the missing .dll.

Please feel free to add your own case studies here! I've made it a community wiki answer.

Comment: it looks like "readelf -d". Is any way to see information about possible load status from "dumpbin"? Something like "ldd"

Comment: This helped me fixed but I had to check the dependencies of my dlls to (I used Qtcore which needed libstdc++, libwinpthread and libgcc).Not having those dll in the folder caused the import error.

Comment: @f222 Yes, this would work just as well. Dumpbin is just one method to check the DLL dependencies, there are others.

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. It gives an insight about any `ImportError` problem where this is the top resulting page.

Answer (score 8):

**Since Python 3.8**, it is possible that [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) or `dumpbin /dependents` reports no dependency issue, but one still gets the error *"The specified module could not be found"*. This is because [the `PATH` variable is no longer used](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#bpo-36085-whatsnew) for resolving DLLs of binary modules!

The solution is to use [os.add_dll_directory](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory):

```py
import os
os.add_dll_directory(r"C:\path\to\your\dll\directory")
import your_module
```

Comment: life saver! The only easy and usable fix!

Answer (score 6):

Installing the [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and 2019](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) worked for me with a similar problem, and helped with another (slightly different) driver issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick note:**
Check if you have other Python versions, if you have removed them, make sure you did that right. If you have Miniconda on your system then Python will not be removed easily.

**What worked for me:** removed other Python versions and the Miniconda, reinstalled Python and the matplotlib library and everything worked great.

Answer (score 2):

I installed [**vc++**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0) which solved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the related packages.

I have the same issue with numpy. I first uninstalled it:

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

and then installed again

```
pip install numpy==1.20.1
```

I needed that specific version. If you want to install other `numpy` versions, you may ignore `==1.20.1`.

Also, during the installation, I received errors such as

> statsmodels 0.12.2 requires patsy>=0.5, which is not installed.

I installed those missing prerequisites as well. e.g.,

```
pip install patsy
```

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled my current **numpy** and installed a wheel numpy from [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) link.

This has solved my issue. I guess we *shoudn't use dll* from random source.

Answer (score 0):

This might be issue of missing Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable packages for Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022 in your machine. Use the following link to download the distributable and install it in your machine.

[VC_redist.x64.exe](https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/2250605e-e48f-43ed-ba6e-e0cc18bc530d/A9F5D2EAF67BF0DB0178B6552A71C523C707DF0E2CC66C06BFBC08BDC53387E7/VC_redist.x64.exe)

For more: [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Latest Supported Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this error and what I found after a lot of investigation:-

issue was in Opencv==4.5.1 build from source with cuda and flag `cuda_with_fast_math=on`

I just rebuild OpenCV and disable

```
cuda_with_fast_math
```

make sure that the shared library builded with cv version matched your current version

and it works for me.