# Import OpenCV under anaconda fails

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I'm trying to use OpenCV under Anaconda for Python2.7.8.final.0.
I did a fresh install of Anaconda, followed by import of the latest (win-64) distribution of OpenCV (2.4.9.1-np19py27_0) using the conda tool...all that seemed to work, the new libraries show up from >conda list.  Everything is in the default locations.

I ran the launcher, updated and then started spyder, and get the following:
From the IPython console prompt:

---

In [1]: import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    import cv

File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cv.py", line 1, in 
    from cv2.cv import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

---

Ok, looks like a simple path issue right?  Similar questions have been answered saying as much.  I go off to look at PYTHONPATH.  In Spyder I find a tool, "PYTHONPATH manager," which shows no path.  Earlier help says the path being misleading is bad, commenting out was the fix, so what should it be?

A second item from the tool menu looks directly at the Windows environment. "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment" key "Path" is blank.

Actually, right-clicking on the python console options *sometimes* gives a view of many more environment variables.  My windows path is:

['C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyQt4',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyQt4',
 'C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core',
 'C:\Anaconda\Scripts',
 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\',
 'C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\',
 'C:\Windows\system32',
 'C:\Windows',
 'C:\Windows\System32\Wbem',
 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\',
 'C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\',
 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\',
 'C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL',
 'C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared',
 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\',
 'C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\',
 'C:\Anaconda',
 'C:\Anaconda\Scripts',
 '']

which looks pretty thorough.

So, what gives?  Did I install it wrong, start it wrong, something else?

Thanks

Comment: unrelated, but try to avoid the deprecated cv2.cv module, it won't be there anymore in near future. stick with cv2.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  Babe in the woods here, I hoped using recent packages from binstar would avoid that sort of thing. If I go edit cv.py to import something else then what should I use?

Comment: check out this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found