# Cannot import pygame into python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I have tried to import pygame 1.9 into both Python 2.7 and 3.5.  I used both Windows 8.1 and 10.  In every case, it does not import the file.  This is the message I get:

```
>>> import pygame

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Pygame is in the `python27\include\pygame` directory.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this question here. It should be an error with missing dlls.

[ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)