# Dependencies error in Matplotlib and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

These versions of softwares are installed :

1. python-2.5
2. numpy-1.0.1.win32-py2.5
3. scipy-0.5.2.win32-py2.5
4. matplotlib-0.87.7.win32-py2.5

[installed in same order]

While running my program, I am getting this error message :

```
*The import of the numpy version of the _transforms module,
_ns_transforms, failed.  This is is either because numpy was
unavailable when matplotlib was compiled, because a dependency of
_ns_transforms could not be satisfied, or because the build flag for
this module was turned off in setup.py.  If it appears that
_ns_transforms was not built, make sure you have a working copy of
numpy and then re-install matplotlib. Otherwise, the following
traceback gives more details:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python25\Scripts\_pictsim.py", line 16, in <module>
from pylab import plot, legend, savefig, gca, vlines, figure, title, xlabel, ylabel, semilogy,\
  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\pylab.py", line 1, in <module>

    >from matplotlib.pylab import *

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pylab.py", line 201, in <module>

    >from axes import Axes, PolarAxes

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 14, in <module>

    >from artist import Artist, setp

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 4, in <module>

    >from transforms import identity_transform

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 223, in <module>

    >from _transforms import Value, Point, Interval, Bbox, Affine

  File "C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_transforms.py", line 17, in <module>

    >from matplotlib._ns_transforms import *

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.*
```

There are some dependency errors, how can I resolve them

While installing numpy, scipy, and matplotlib it says : could not create key and set key value

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by downloading 2 dll files and copying in system32 and syswow64

Got this answer from another similar stackoverflow question

[ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)