# cannot import pandas after conda update, Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conda

I have been using pandas for a long while now, and wanted to use this functionality. Realizing I was in a prior version I typed `conda update pandas` into my command line.

Now, when I go into python and try to import pandas I see the following:

```
C:\Users\%USER%>python
Python 2.7.10 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, May 28 2015, 17:02:00) [MSC
v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", l
ine 18, in <module>
    raise ImportError("Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_depende
ncies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
>>>
```

If I just try to import numpy i see:

```
    >>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", li
ne 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py",
 line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py"
, line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.p
y", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\%USER%\Miniconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py
", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This was working perfectly until this conda update. Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: You can reinstall numpy and pandas.

Comment: @Razik given this error, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure about this but I think numpy is the main problem here. Try to install/ update numpy. may be that can solve the probelm. And install Installing the Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2015 for dll problem. 
you can see here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: Try to update numpy as well: `conda update numpy`

Comment: Problem solved below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully conda understands revisions.

```
C:\>conda list --revisions
```

Will give you your list of revisions. Find the one prior to the most recent that broke stuff.

For me it was revision 6, so I typed:

```
C:\>conda install --revision 6
```

I am up and running again!