# win8.1 64 bit + python 2.7.3 + import htql; ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll

This is the first time to use python and need to import htql

when i run this code:

```
import htql;
page="<a href=a.html>1</a><a href=b.html>2</a><a href=c.html>3</a>";
query="<a>:href,tx";
for url, text in htql.HTQL(page, query):
     print(url, text);
```

i got the following error:

**import htql; ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nik26.png)

i trys to to solve error as refered here [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

**BUT error still exists!!**

Also i am  Installing the Visual C++ Redistributable für Visual Studio 2015 from this links: https://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=48145 
to fix the missing DLLs

**BUT error still exists!**

Please help!

THNAKS IN ADVANCE ..

Comment: this is definitely HTQL package broken setup or misconfiguration. Adjusting your question with description of how you did installed this package can shed some light on what went wrong

Comment: I installed it as described here:http://htql.net/htql-com-manual.pdf

Comment: instructions within PDF manual are for COM interface (e.g. to use by C++ application), python does not use such. For usage from python scripts you should try in install it as described on http://htql.net website start page - unzip archive sutable for your version of python  into python installation DLLs subdirectory

Comment: thanks it worked (Y)

Comment: @agg3l you can post your reply as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of the questioner is he followed installation instructions from HTQL PDF-manual named *Hyper-Text Query Language COM Interface*, which obviously describes library setup for COM ([Component Object Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) by Microsoft), proposing `regsvr32 <path-to-dll>`. Intended to be used within win32-infrastructure aware applications first place

While there are means to use COM from within python (e.g. via [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and others), it's not common method python script expects.

Proper solution is to follow instructions from HTQL [home page](http://htql.net), suggesting:

> **Windows binaries**: Download the htql.zip and extract "htql.pyd" to the Python's DLLs directory, such as in 'C:\Python27\DLLs\' or 'C:\Python32\DLLs\'.

to install precompiled python *.pyd* module within python libraries search path