# _iterative import Error in Python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I've been trying to run a code with python 3.4, but getting the error mentionned below. I tried all the other solutions suggested by the others in the other topics but nothing worked.
Thanks for the help

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\daly\Documents\Python\Machine Learning\regression.py", line 
    4, in <module>
    from sklearn import preprocessing, cross_validation, svm, cluster
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 134, in 
    <module>
    from .base import clone
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py", line 11, in 
    <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 18, in 
    <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
    File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\fixes.py", line 278, in 
    <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\isolve\iterative.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module spécifié est introuvable.
```

Comment: this may be the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Comment: no, but thanks anyway, he is having a problem with maplotlib, mine is with Scipy.

Comment: is that the complete traceback btw?

Comment: no, i thought the first part was useless, since it all traces back to that one

Comment: i have just edited my post to contain the complete traceback, thanks for your help