# ImportError in anaconda3 : DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, anaconda

I have run this in Anaconda 3:

```
from PIL import Image
```

and it shows DLL error. I check for solution on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and did accordingly but then also there is error.

```
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b7f01c2f8cfe> in <module>()
----> 1 from PIL import Image

~\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     56     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     57     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 58     from . import _imaging as core
     59     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     60         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to uninstall the package from anaconda and then install it with pip:

conda uninstall pillow:

```
Conda remove Pillow
```

Install pillow with pip:

```
pip install pillow
```

Comment: Worked for me! In order to remove `pillow` using `conda` on Windows, we should be logged in as Administrator otherwise the console freezes on `Solving Environment`