# I am having trouble installing Tensorflow - gpu into my anaconda virtual enviorment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

Every time I try and re-install Cuda it fails and whenever I try and import Tensorflow with the current set up I have it will pip install but it will not import and will instead return:

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > >         File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > >           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > >         File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
> > >           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >         File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
> > >           return _load(spec)
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 22, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\MBUSI\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.4.10-py36_0\Library\bin\conda\envs\tensorflow2\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

Comment: Are you sure that your GPU is CUDA compatible ? then which version of Python are you using ?

Comment: I am using 3.6, I have a NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX GPU, I was able to install CUDA by doing a custom install without the Visual Studios checkbox clicked

Answer (score 0):

This is basically DLL load error. The answer is already given in the past posts. 
[DLL failed-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found),[DLL load failed during Pytorch](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/9263),[DLL failure 3](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10033)