# scrapy installed but can't import it

Tags: python

Can't open scrapy, it is installed successfully and shows in `pip freeze`

```
C:\Users\tim_t\Desktop>scrapy shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\tim_t\Anaconda3\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from scrapy.spiders import Spider
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scrapy.http import Request
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from scrapy.http.request.form import FormRequest
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 11, in <module>
    import lxml.html
  File "c:\users\tim_t\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .. import etree
ImportError: DLL load failed
```

I tried the answers from [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) but it didn't help
any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there some other message after "_DLL load failed_"?

Comment: @GinoMempin it was in german (for some reason), but here it is  `Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden`

Comment: I think the error isn't exactly related to scrapy, but to `etree` (or to `lxml`) and it's compatibility with windows.