# Problems with Jupyter python kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I have been looking to use Jupyter for some upcoming projects and decided to go ahead and set it up. When I select the "Python" under kernels when creating a new notebook, the following error occurs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 476, in write_connection_file
    kernel_name=self.kernel_name
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 141, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 424, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

` Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: The answer in this question might offer some help
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall anaconda and create virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you, installing anaconda and launching Jupyter from there solved the issue!