# Cannot import python module pyo

Tags: python, module, pip, python-import, pyo

I'm trying to import pyo for this project I'm working on but this is the output I get when I try to do so:

```
Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .lib import analysis as analysis
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\lib\analysis.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ._core import *
  File "C:\Users\spark\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyo\lib\_core.py", line 58, in <module>
    from .._pyo import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I've tried uninstalling and downgrading pyo but I can't seem to get it to import. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try to downgrade to pyo 0.8.6 I saw some people get rid of this issue by installing that version. Link -> http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/pyo-older-releases/

Comment: So I installed the 0.8.6 version and instead of getting the weird DLL error it just says that there is no module named pyo now

Comment: Did you use `pip3` to install the package?

Comment: I tried using pip3 but it still gives me an error when I try to install it

Comment: I'm not a windows user, but i think this is more general issue and not only PYO importation. Maybe this can help you fix this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230455/1863647

Comment: when getting install errors, always most helpful to post those errors

Comment: works for me on , Python 3.8.8 , docs confirm Requires: Python >=3.6, <4 https://pypi.org/project/pyo/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/73508905/4788546