# Can't install pyo using pip

Tags: python, linux, windows, pip, pyo

When trying to install pyo using pip I get error

$ pip install pyo

```
Collecting pyo 
 Using cached pyo-1.0.4.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-06kfbyzb\pyo_9bd28f6f7eba4c5aa2896ae564b089f6\setup.py", line 293, in <module>
          for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path)
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Then I tried

$ pip install pyo --use-deprecated=backtrack-on-build-failures

```
DEPRECATION: Backtracking on build failures can mask issues related to how a package generates metadata or builds a wheel. This flag will be removed in pip 22.2. A possible replacement is avoiding known-bad versions by explicitly telling pip to ignore them (either directly as requirements, or via a constraints file). Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10655
Collecting pyo
  Using cached pyo-1.0.4.tar.gz (6.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_t68yako\pyo_d26c3df31ce44e44babd1e5def6de075\setup.py", line 293, in <module>
          for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path)
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/4a/a681a4c1c6db790b39f24c3384debedd583db48bea47362640ebcab1f3a6/pyo-1.0.4.tar.gz#sha256=34937eba641ed6b1c8ede1c35f30ad5e08493ec1f09352398790910bfd19d445 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyo/) (requires-python:>=3.6, <4) due to build failure: metadata generation failed
  Using cached pyo-1.0.3.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_t68yako\pyo_3f80885b827046bbb8de3e7c16e16c7b\setup.py", line 215, in <module>
          [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")])]
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/ea/e717ec9cef74dc4a26000b29b1cf8703e2871d9edaae189dc515d8e74910/pyo-1.0.3.tar.gz#sha256=f0d187a78e3ab9f10275853a22b6a08094aeed4e0c2adee8697734373aa8dd1f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyo/) (requires-python:>=3.6, <4) due to build failure: metadata generation failed
  Using cached pyo-1.0.2.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_t68yako\pyo_7636aa31397442f693130603d4cb92d8\setup.py", line 215, in <module>
          [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")])]
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/48/2b5ea0d2e52edbb3d440fbbf7992f52c9727b2c4117f11b6348abf51706b/pyo-1.0.2.tar.gz#sha256=cb716d2c38a02f3aafba2cb5a47af67d78433580f6536c57fd0883283d3bf64a (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyo/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <4) due to build failure: metadata generation failed
  Using cached pyo-1.0.1.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_t68yako\pyo_9550d20742e24085af8ace9202cb7913\setup.py", line 212, in <module>
          [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")])]
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9c/f2/87f07599a2f107f02a9f7cf11599c5eecf37662356296e1236c17ec997f4/pyo-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=e85a3e9e4e17769c4178c907e6b8f01bc455fe0fa348b0ce64d5698ec7e82202 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyo/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <4) due to build failure: metadata generation failed
  Using cached pyo-1.0.0.tar.gz (5.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\VA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_t68yako\pyo_712915a0221348b59415409f622bde9f\setup.py", line 211, in <module>
          [os.path.join(data_files_common_path, f) for f in os.listdir(data_files_common_path) if f.endswith(".dll")])]
      FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'win64dlls\\win64_pyo_data_files_common'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/0f/2c3f9fb88effc62571c209525b5e84d1ec0b68611c916daa96ae8c84f43f/pyo-1.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=4ad45d32ae6ef5865762594223bddf0d6efa7e45657b899b16cda33ce328ebfd (from https://pypi.org/simple/pyo/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*, !=3.4.*, <4) due to build failure: metadata generation failed
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyo (from versions: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyo
```

The python version

$ python --version

Python 3.10.4

Tried to install  [AJAX SOUND STUDIO pyo](http://ajaxsoundstudio.com/software/pyo/pyo-older-releases/)

For AJax Sound studio I tried with latest pyo 0.9.1 but still error persists so I tried with pyo 0.8.4.

Still the issue is not solved.

The above terminal output is from Anaconda Promt from Windows. I also tried to install pyo in Ubuntu. In that OS also I am facing issues with installing PYO.

Terminal output for installation in Ubuntu

$ pip install pyo

[Terminal output](https://gist.github.com/VineethKumar7/fda084fe77eb6edc5e3668df27c4453a)

tried to install pyo using conda but package is not found

$ conda install pyo

Comment: Try with *Python 3. **9***.

Comment: Python 3.9.12 installs pyo

Comment: Will do. Please give me some time to try something.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I had an issue with  installing pyo using pip. Got solved by downgrading python version to 3.9 as CristiFati mentioned. So waiting for  CristiFati answer so that I can mark that as answer.

Comment: Could you please test the *.whl* that I built for *Python 3.10*. I want to see if it behaves well in your environment / scenario (and it doesn't contain bugs that I didn't detect in my (shallow) test)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [[PyPI]: pyo **1.0.4** - Download files](https://pypi.org/project/pyo/1.0.4/#files) (newest published version at answer time), prebuilt *.whl*s (for *Win*) are available if **all** below apply:

- *Python* version: *v3.9*, *v3.8*, *v3.7*, *v3.6*
- *Python* *arch*: *pc064* (*win_amd64*)

Also, building from sources (fall back if no prebuilt *.whl* available), is complex (and **doesn't work *OOTB*** - only tried for *Win*, but I'm 99% sure that it's the same for *Nix*) as it requires some additional steps (building / using a bunch of dependencies), so the error pops up (if fixed, another will, and so on).

So, stick with supported *Python* versions until a new *PyO* version will be released (this one is ***1+*** year old). 
Of course building from sources is an option, but it requires deeper knowledge.

---

#### Update *#0*

Built *.whl*s and published them on **[[GitHub]: CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries - (master) Prebuilt-Binaries/PyO/v1.0.4](https://github.com/CristiFati/Prebuilt-Binaries/tree/master/PyO/v1.0.4)** (*win_amd64* for *Python*: *v3.11*, *v3.10* **and** *win32* for current *Python* versions). Check [[SO]: Installing pygraphviz on Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.6 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54890705/4788546) (*Shortcut* section at the end) for details regarding custom *.whl* installation.

I used the following script to (quickly) test them.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import time

import pyo


def main(*argv):
    sample_name = "Sine"
    sample_class = getattr(pyo, sample_name, None)
    if sample_class is None:
        print("Invalid sample: {:s}".format(sample_name))
        return -1
    secs = 2
    out_file = "{:s}.wav".format(sample_name)
    srv = pyo.Server().boot()
    print("Playing sound ({:s}) for {:.3f} seconds (and saving to '{:s}') ...".format(sample_name, secs, out_file))
    srv.start()
    srv.recstart(out_file)
    sample = sample_class(mul=0.01).out()
    print("Sample: {:}".format(sample))
    time.sleep(secs)
    srv.recstop()
    srv.stop()
    sfp = pyo.SfPlayer(out_file)
    print("SFP: {:}".format(sfp))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073508905]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]> :: ------- PYTHON 3.10 -------
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install "e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\Prebuilt-Binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl"
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Processing e:\work\dev\github\cristifati\prebuilt-binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl
> Installing collected packages: pyo
> Successfully installed pyo-1.0.4
> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
>
> WxPython is not found for the current python version.
> Pyo will use a minimal GUI toolkit written with Tkinter (if available).
> This toolkit has limited functionnalities and is no more
> maintained or updated. If you want to use all of pyo's
> GUI features, you should install WxPython, available here:
> http://www.wxpython.org/
>
> Python 3.10.1 (tags/v3.10.1:2cd268a, Dec  6 2021, 19:10:37) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Pyo warning: Portmidi closed.
> Playing sound (Sine) for 2.000 seconds (and saving to 'Sine.wav') ...
> Sample: < Instance of Sine class >
> SFP: < Instance of SfPlayer class >
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ------- PYTHON 3.11 -------
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.11_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install "e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\Prebuilt-Binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl"
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Processing e:\work\dev\github\cristifati\prebuilt-binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl
> Installing collected packages: pyo
> Successfully installed pyo-1.0.4
> WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.11_test0\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.11_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
>
> WxPython is not found for the current python version.
> Pyo will use a minimal GUI toolkit written with Tkinter (if available).
> This toolkit has limited functionnalities and is no more
> maintained or updated. If you want to use all of pyo's
> GUI features, you should install WxPython, available here:
> http://www.wxpython.org/
>
> Python 3.11.0rc1 (main, Aug  8 2022, 11:30:54) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Pyo warning: Portmidi closed.
> Playing sound (Sine) for 2.000 seconds (and saving to 'Sine.wav') ...
> Sample: < Instance of Sine class >
> SFP: < Instance of SfPlayer class >
>
> Done.
>
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: ------- PYTHON 3.7 (!!! PC032 !!!) -------
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install "e:\Work\Dev\GitHub\CristiFati\Prebuilt-Binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl"
> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
> Processing e:\work\dev\github\cristifati\prebuilt-binaries\pyo\v1.0.4\pyo-1.0.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
> Installing collected packages: pyo
> Successfully installed pyo-1.0.4
> WARNING: You are using pip version 20.3.3; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
> You should consider upgrading via the 'e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.07_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
>
> WxPython is not found for the current python version.
> Pyo will use a minimal GUI toolkit written with Tkinter (if available).
> This toolkit has limited functionnalities and is no more
> maintained or updated. If you want to use all of pyo's
> GUI features, you should install WxPython, available here:
> http://www.wxpython.org/
>
> Python 3.7.9 (tags/v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 17 2020, 18:01:55) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] 032bit on win32
>
> Pyo warning: Portmidi closed.
> Playing sound (Sine) for 2.000 seconds (and saving to 'Sine.wav') ...
> Sample: < Instance of Sine class >
> SFP: < Instance of SfPlayer class >
>
> Done.
> ```

**Note**: Needless to say that during each run, an annoying high pitch sound (corresponding to default frequency) was playing for 2 seconds.