# How do you fix this error: "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found." using PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, python-import

I am currently using Python 3.6.8 and PyQt5. My program was working fine but after a Windows Update, everything stopped working.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the environment variables have become corrupt after the update. In the simplest case, it should just be

Adding your DLL location of python, for example,

> (C:\Program Files\Python35\DLLs)

in the `path` in Environment variables. You can also see some others [possible solutions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I re-installed everything (using the command in my post below) and now it works.

Comment: It is not the problem of dll

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this error by running the following command on my command prompt:

```
pip install pyqt5-tools
```

Comment: `Because pyqt5-tools (5.15.4.3.0.3) depends on both pyqt5-plugins (<empty>) and pyqt5-plugins (<empty>), pyqt5-tools is forbidden.` Odd

Answer (score 0):

Change your interpreter you are using in the IDE i.e. use the same version of python which is running in your cmd prompt. This solved my error.