# Can't import numpy from cmd

Tags: python, cmd, anaconda, python-import

I have a Project working in PyCharm with the Anaconda3 Python 3.7 interpreter. When I run it **from PyCharm there is no issue**, but when I run it from `cmd` (same interpreter) with:

```
c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\python main.py
```

I get:

```
    File "c:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\LibreriaDerivados\Calculator\Calculator.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

So I checked just accessing Python in `cmd` works, but then inside when I do `import numpy` I get the same error.

Additional info:

- dir `C:\users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\numpy` exists.
- Inside that dir `__init__.py`, `__distributor_init.py` files exist, but no `_mklinit` file.
- There is a `_mklinit.cp37-win_amd64.pyd` file. Making a copy named `_mklinit.pyd` won't help.

Comment: Maybe these are different python.exe in cmd in PyCharm? Try checking with `which python` or `where python` to make sure which executable is invoked.

Comment: @Evgeny `where python` does return a different Python path from the one that PyCharm uses, but as I mentioned, to run my Project in `cmd` I first navigated to the PyCharm interpreter folder (…\Continuum\anaconda3\) and then run `python main.py`

Comment: I might be wrong, but running just different interpreter isn't enough - the import of libraries still goes from folders found on PATH, I suspect. Either you carve out another python installation, or change PATH or use virtual envs, these are the options.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I remember a long time ago I had this same issue

I solved it by going to my cmd, and going to the python scripts directory

cd "C:\Users\micha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts"

THEN do pip install Whatever, then it should work

Or check your PATH maybe

Answer (score -1):

A similar issue was resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) with matplotlib not being found. Not sure if your issue is exactly the same but here's their solution:

(I found this answer from a video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xmvRF7koJ5E)

1. Download msvcp71.dll and msvcr71.dll from the web.
2. Save them to your C:\Windows\System32 folder.
3. Save them to your C:\Windows\SysWOW64 folder as well (if you have a 64-bit operating system).