# What's the difference? DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application & DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, dll, importerror

I came across both issues these days when working on Python and DLL files. What's the difference between these two ImportErrors?

Comment: It might be because you don't seem to be asking a question. Rather, you are asking/answering the question at the same time. It might be best to edit the question into an actual question and then post your findings as an answer instead?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

From my research, I figured out part of the answers to this question.

The first one, `DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application` is probably due to the mix up of the bit version 64 and bit version 32. As such, to my understanding, if I am running a code compiled in Python 2 in Python 3, the problem will happen. The solution to this issue is to use the consistent bit version.

Another one, `DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found`, is probably caused by:

(1) Inconsistent compile version: the code is compiled with a different compiler (or compiler version) than the binary file that the respective Python module consists of ([reference](https://kb.froglogic.com/squish/troubleshoot/importerror-dll-load-failed-specified-module-could-found/)). In my case, my code was compiled in Python 3.4, and the error raised when I imported the module in Python 3.6.

(2) The path to the file is misconfigured ([reference](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-%E2%80%9CImportError-DLL-load-failed-The-specified-module-could-not-be-found%E2%80%9D-in-Python-3))

(3) Some files or "dependencies" are missing ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)). For example, need to install the Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 in some cases.

Please leave your feedback if I was wrong or the answer can be improved. Thank you!