# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. Failed to execute script

Tags: python, tkinter

I am getting this error when .py is converted into .exe file. How can it be fixed?

```
  File "Final.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skopt\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\skopt\acquisition.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py", line 388, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 174, in <module>
  File "c:\users\sel\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\scipy\spatial\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[12932] Failed to execute script Final
```

Comment: Did you create the exe in a 64-bit Python?

Comment: Are you sure your opening the exe from the `dist` folder ?

Comment: @acw1668 normal 32 bit

Comment: @CoolCloud yes I am

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)