# Why does pdftotext throw DLL load failed error, on windows10, python3.7

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, pdftotext

```
   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\screener\screener\urls.py", line 15, in <module>
    from userbase import views as user_views
  File "D:\screener\userbase\views.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .forms import (
  File "D:\screener\userbase\forms.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .import_companies import get_codes_from_file
  File "D:\screener\userbase\import_companies.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utilities.file_to_text import get_text
  File "D:\screener\utilities\file_to_text.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pdftotext
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I installed folling https://coder.haus/2019/09/27/installing-pdftotext-through-pip-on-windows-10/ , and tried reinstalling using pip command, also tried it inside conda but all yielded the same result

I am unable to import pdftotext, any way to get it done?

Comment: how many python interpreters do you have installed? And are you sure you are using the correct one for this?

Comment: Got only one python interpreter installed, and installing the project along with its dependencies
For pdftotext, i used pip install since i had the poppler issue, but eve after installation it didn't let me import it
Throwing the above error

Comment: Poppler issue? I do not see this in the question

Comment: No no, I got across the poppler issue, even used pip install to install pdftotext
Ended up with the DLL load failed issue

Comment: this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found