# couchbase using python import

Tags: python, couchbase

Im using Pycharm and trying to import couchbase
using python 3.7.3

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sergi/PycharmProjects/cocuhbase_exemple/couchbase_exemple.py", line 2, in <module>
    import couchbase
  File "C:\Users\sergi\.virtualenvs\sergi-4BQybWtk\lib\site-packages\couchbase\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import couchbase_core._bootstrap
  File "C:\Users\sergi\.virtualenvs\sergi-4BQybWtk\lib\site-packages\couchbase_core\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    import couchbase_core._libcouchbase as _LCB
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: Why did you tag this question with couchdb if it's about couchbase

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip install couchbase==3.0.1
```

I had the same problem for latest version of couchbase. this solved !