# ImportError: DLL load failed

Tags: python

I need to import a module from spacepy: irbempy. After,

```
from spacepy import irbempy
```

I get an error saying

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing irbempylib: The specified module could not be found
```

When I follow the error, it says it came from line 31 within irbempy:

```
28  import spacepy.coordinates as spc
29  import spacepy.datamodel as dm
30  try:
31      from . import irbempylib as oplib
32  except ImportError:
33      if 'sphinx' in sys.argv[0]:
34          warnings.warn('Could not import irbempylib. '
35                        'You appear to be building docs, so ignoring this error.')
36      else:
37          raise
```

How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: That question is kinda similar here:
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

Comment: I thought the same. Unfortunately, I tried those answers but none have worked.