# Unable to import required dependencies: numpy

Tags: pandas, numpy, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm trying to build a visual dashboard in VS Code using dash. But I can't get past this error I'm getting:

> Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be
> found.   File "C:\Users\ko14Z57\plots.py", line 1, in 
> import pandas as pd
>
> Exception has occurred: ImportError Unable to import required
> dependencies: numpy:

I'm using python 3.6.13 but I've tried this with python 3.9 and 3.8. I also tried installing\uninstalling numpy and pandas. I'm using Anaconda for my package management. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could the issue be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20201868/9098350)?

Answer (score 2):

in vscode from `view>command palette` write 'select your default profile' the select 'Command Prompt' or 'cmd.exe'

Answer (score 0):

[Assuming that Bas may be right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68714352/unable-to-import-required-dependencies-numpy#comment121439522_68714352), and you're missing the Microsoft C++ compiler.  Try installing Microsoft's "C/C++ Extension Pack": https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack .  You can find it in VSCode by clicking the extensions icon at the left side and searching "cpptools".

[image: Microsoft's "C/C++ Extension Pack"]

Comment: Can you provide additional details (like the error text)? I recommend editing your question

Comment: I solved it and my answer here is above your answer, now i think my error was a bit different than this question

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using conda, I updated conda and then updated all of my packages and that worked.

```
conda update conda
conda update --all
```

Note: I'm on Python 3.9 on a Windows machine.

Probably unnecessary, but I also added the interpreter path to my launch.json file:

```
"python": "C:\\Users\\<username>\\Anaconda3\\python.exe"
```