# How to build a package with Cython, C++ and gmp on Windows with Mingw?

Tags: python, c++, cython, mingw-w64, gmp

When I try to compile a Cython project with submodules using the gmp library and including C ++ files, I get an error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ...
```

In particular, I want to wrap in Cython a class written in C++, which use GMP, by using Mingw64 as compiler.
I use Python3.8 and Mingw64 has been is installed by means of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).

---

In the following, I provide you with a minimal reproducible example (as asked by @ead).

The directory tree is as follows:

```
project
  setup.py
  pytest.py
 
  include
    test.h
    test.cpp

  test    
    submodule
      cy_test.pxd
      cy_test.pyx
```

where, in `project/include`, I putted the class written in C++ I want to wrap.

`project/include/test.h` is

```
#ifndef TEST_LIB
#define TEST_LIB

#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
    private:
        mpz_t n;
    public:
        Test();
        Test(const char* expr);
        virtual ~Test()
        {
            mpz_clear(this->n);
        }
};

#endif // TEST_LIB
```

whereas `project/include/test.cpp` is

```
#ifndef TEST_IMPL
#define TEST_IMPL

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <test.h>

Test::Test()
{
    mpz_init_set_ui(this->n, 0);
}

Test::Test(const char* expr)
{
    mpz_init_set_str(this->n, expr, 10);
}

#endif // TEST_IMPL
```

`project/test/submodule/cy_test.pxd` is:

```
cdef extern from "test.cpp":
    pass
# Declare the class with cdef
cdef extern from "test.h":
    cdef cppclass Test:
        Test() except +
        Test(char* n) except +
```

Instead, `project/test/submodule/cy_test.pyx` is:

```
from test.submodule.cy_test cimport Test

cdef class PyTest:
    cdef Test* n    
    def __cinit__(self, object n):
        cdef char* string = n
        self.n = new Test(string)
    
    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.n
```

The file `project/pytest.py` is simply an import of cy_test:

```
from test.submodule import cy_test
```

Finally, `project/setup.py` is:

```
import os
import sys
from setuptools import find_packages
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.clean import clean
from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import Extension


os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"


MINGW_DIR = "C:/msys64/mingw64"

CWD = os.getcwd()
BASE_DIRS = [os.path.join(CWD, "include"), os.path.join(CWD, "test"), get_python_inc(), "C:/Program Files/Python38"]
INCLUDE_DIRS = [os.path.join(MINGW_DIR, "include")] + BASE_DIRS
LIB_DIRS = [os.path.join(MINGW_DIR, "lib")]
EXTRA_ARGS = ["-O3", "-std=c++17"]
EXTRA_LINK_ARGS = []
LIBRARIES = ["gmp", "gmpxx", "mpc", "mpfr"]
EXTRA_LIBRARIES = []

ext = [
    Extension(
        name="test.submodule.cy_test", 
        sources=["./test/submodule/cy_test.pyx"],
        language="c++",
        include_dirs=INCLUDE_DIRS,
        library_dirs=LIB_DIRS,
        libraries=LIBRARIES,
        extra_link_args=EXTRA_LINK_ARGS,
        extra_compile_args=EXTRA_ARGS,
        extra_objects=EXTRA_LIBRARIES,
        cython_cplus=True,
        cython_c_in_temp=True)
]

setup(
    name="test",
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_dir={
        "test": "test", 
        "test/submodule": "test/submodule"},
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data={
        'test': ['*.pyx', '*.pxd', '*.h', '*.c', '*.cpp', '*.dll'],
        'test/submodule': ['*.pyx', '*.pxd', '*.h', '*.c', '*.cpp']
    },
    cmdclass={'clean': clean, 'build_ext': build_ext},
    include_dirs=BASE_DIRS,
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext,
        compiler_directives={
            'language_level': "3str",
            "c_string_type": "str",
            "c_string_encoding": "utf-8"},
        force=True,
        cache=False,
        quiet=False),
    )
```

I compile `setup.py` as `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32` in order to use MinGW and `g++.exe` as, by default on Windows, the compiler is taken from Visual Studio, which gives me other errors like `undefined reference to '__gmpz_init'`.

The compilation ends without errors, but when I run the `pytest.py` script I get the following error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cy_test
```

I have already dumped `cy_test.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` as in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found) and I have got this:

```
Dump of file cy_test.cp38-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Image has the following dependencies:

    KERNEL32.dll
    msvcrt.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-private-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll
    api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll
    libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
    libstdc++-6.dll
    libgmp-10.dll
    python38.dll

  Summary

        1000 .CRT
        1000 .bss
        1000 .data
        1000 .edata
        2000 .idata
        1000 .pdata
        2000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        4000 .text
        1000 .tls
        1000 .xdata
```

How can I solve? I have already seen on [cython-github-issues](https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/3213) that, by including the following two lines in `pytest.py`

```
import os
os.add_dll_directory(mingw64_bin_path)
```

the above error disappear and the `submodule` is imported correctly, but I would like a solution that avoids including the Mingw path outside the setup (assuming it exists).

Comment: So, can you build a very simple extension with gcc? I would say no, but then your post is so long I'm not sure. You need to provide a [mre] (minimal being important)...

Comment: @ead I build successfully an extension with g++. The problem is that the `pyd` of `cy_integer_class` require some DLLs which are inside the bin directory of mingw64. By the way, I have just added another response in order to provide the `integer.cpp` and `integer.h` files. I'm sorry but I am not able to reduce the example as this problem exist in this specific case. Maybe there is the same problem by implementing only one function in C++, but honestly I do not know. If you can wait me, I will try tomorrow as, unfortunately, I cannot do it now

Comment: I would try to build an extension with just print(42) inside, try to load it and to see if it works. I assume it would not. But it is up to you, whether you want handle one problem after another or all at once.

Comment: @ead A simple extension works with no errors and can be imported successfully. Problems arise when I include `integer.cpp` and its `pyx` wrapper.

Comment: Please don't post answers that don't seek to answer the question. If you have updates to your question, you can edit your question to include the update. If you're hitting the limit on how much code you can include, then you're including too much code and need to reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: @meagar I updated the question and I putted the minimal reproducible example

Comment: @G.F That is much better and clearer now

Comment: You use c++, so at least the funtionality found in libstdc++-6.dll must be provided somehow (and probably libgcc_s_seh-1.dll) , e.g. be distributed with your extension. One possibility could be to put the dll-files  next to resulting pyd or to update path automatically in the \_\_init\_\_.py of the module.

Comment: @ead I have just tried to put the dll-files next to the resulting pyd, but it does not works. I putted them in submodule directory and pyd file does not cares about them.

Comment: @ead I just found a solution. I putted in the end of the problem. Should I add an answer with the solution or can I leave the solution at the end of the question?

Comment: @G.F If it is a solution, it should be an answer (addition to the problem/updates should go into the question). It is Ok to answer own question.

Comment: @ead Ok, thanks. I just added the solution as an answer, and I removed it from the main question. Anyway, it is very confusing the forced shared option in setuptools for the mingw compiler...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just accidentally found the solution to the above problem. The problem is the package `setuptools` (which in my case is the version 60.9.1)! Indeed, by executing `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --compiler=mingw32`, the latter will call the class `Mingw32CCompiler` into `setuptools/_distutils/cygwinccompiler.py` which contains these two lines:

```
...
shared_option = "-shared"
...
self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()
```

These lines will produce the compiling command `g++ -shared ... -lucrt -lvcruntime140`, that is, the `pyd` file, generated by this latter command, would be a shared library which needs a lot of dll dependencies in order to be executed. In order to avoid these dependencies, it is mandatory to comment the line `self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()`, which as a consequence removes `-lucrt -lvcruntime140` from the compilation command. Furthermore, one has to modify the `setup.py` by substituting `EXTRA_LINK_ARGS = []` with `EXTRA_LINK_ARGS = ["-static"]` in order to get the following compiling command: `g++ -shared ... -static`, which builds the `pyd` file as a static library that have no dll dependencies. Indeed, after the above modifications, by dumping `cy_test.cp38-win_amd64.pyd` we get:

```
Dump of file cy_test.cp38-win_amd64.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Summary

        1000 .CRT
        1000 .bss
        4000 .data
        1000 .edata
        2000 .idata
        C000 .pdata
       16000 .rdata
        2000 .reloc
       E8000 .text
        1000 .tls
       10000 .xdata
```

I wonder why MSVCR it is not optional for the MinGW compiler in `setuptools`...