# Converting Polars to Pandas raises error DLL load failed while importing lib

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, python-polars

I am practicing Pythons using Polars. I have a data-frame which I have generated a bunch of calculations in my data-frame and then want to convert it to a Pandas data-frame so that I can apply an isolation forest to the the dataset. I have installed polars and pyarrow and pandas using

My Code and version of the packages is below. I have windows as my OS

```py
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pandas                    1.5.3           py310h1c4a608_1    https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
pandas-flavor             0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge
polars                    0.20.5                   pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   10.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow-hotfix            0.6                pyhd8ed1ab_0    https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge

# ADD OUTLIER COLUMNS---------------------------------------------------------
# Using Isolation Forests to find outliers
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
features = df_calc.drop('status')
features.to_pandas()

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: The specified module could not be found.
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you check the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20201868/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem.  I use Anaconda/Jupyter Notebook, and I usually install packages from within a Notebook with a **!{sys.executable} -mpip install *<package_name>*** command.  So I tried this:

**!{sys.executable} -mpip install pyarrow**

`Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (14.0.2)`
`Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.6 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.26.3)`

But it did not solve the problem.  And then I tried this (notice the "-U" parameter):

**!{sys.executable} -mpip install -U pyarrow**

`Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (14.0.2)`
`Collecting pyarrow`
  `Downloading pyarrow-15.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)`
`Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2,>=1.16.6 in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.26.3)`
`Downloading pyarrow-15.0.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (24.9 MB)`
   `---------------------------------------- 0.0/24.9 MB ? eta -:--:--`
[...]
   `---------------------------------------- 24.9/24.9 MB 22.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00`
`Installing collected packages: pyarrow`
  `Attempting uninstall: pyarrow`
    `Found existing installation: pyarrow 14.0.2`
    `Uninstalling pyarrow-14.0.2:`
      `Successfully uninstalled pyarrow-14.0.2`
`Successfully installed pyarrow-15.0.0`\

That worked for me.  Good luck!

But as Wayne points out in his comment below, this is more of a workaround than a solution.  I was looking for a quick fix, I found one that worked, and I decided to share it with John Smith (and possibly other viewers too) who may have been waiting 11 days for an answer.

That is precisely what I love about StackOverflow: there is always place for improvement and further learning through comments!

*BerPa*

Comment: ... of course you need to **``import sys``** beforehand!

Comment: You should be using Anaconda/conda to install if you chose Anaconda Distribution as you primary package manager. Mixing pip with conda is a recipe for headaches. Only resort to it when there's no conda recipe. Plus conda has abilities that pip doesn't and will more likely work for complex installs than pip. For pyarrow you can use `%conda install conda-forge::pyarrow` run in a new cell in your running `.ipynb` file. That is based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyarrow) and ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). The latter link details the magic install commands that were added in 2019 to make sure the installation run inside a notebook occurs in the proper environment where the kernel is running. It is a lot less complex than your version of the install command and it is nearly universal in modern Jupyter, working in Google Colab and JupyterLite now as well as JupyterLab 4 and Jupyter Notebook 7 & NbClassic.

Comment: I should have included the other reason to use `pip` even though you are using Anaconda/ conda is when you are troubleshooting and have exhausted absolutely all other options. And though it may work to get past the present hurdle, know that it doesn't bode well for the robustness and portability of your current environment.

Comment: Thank you Wayne for your precisions.  I know that I was fixing a broken table leg with duct tape here...  After an Anaconda update, my code suddenly stopped working, and I needed to move quickly.  To be honest, I hate to struggle with these various ways of installing packages.  I take good note of your experience, and I certainly will read those documents you are pointing out.

Comment: I totally understand. I just thought I'd round things out with some measured concerns, advice, and options for others.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time out to review the question.
I found the solution to my problem *that worked for me*.
It seems to be that the version of pyarrow was too high on my system.

- I went to the anaconda website and found the version below version 10.
- I then removed the newer version of pyarrow from my PC and installed the lower version.
- I restarted my IDE and now the package works

Thank you again for your answers. They certainly helped my think my problem through